# Office Add-in development: Insert table in Word 2016

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-addins, office-js

I am trying to insert a table using Office.js inside the body of a document but to no avail.

I have used the following code:

```
function insertSampleTable() {

    showNotification("Insert Table", "Inserting table...")

    Word.run(function (context) {
        // Create a proxy object for the document body.
        var body = context.document.body;

        body.insertTable(2, 2, Word.InsertLocation.end, ["a"]);

        // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
        return context.sync();
    })
    .catch(errorHandler);

}
```

But upon clicking the button, it gives me the error below:

```
Error: TypeError: Object doesn't support property or method 'insertTable'
```

Any help will be appreciated. I have tried to check the Microsoft Office Dev site but they don't have any samples like this one.

Thanks!

Comment: Michael we added a table object as part of the 1.3 APIs. check the open spec: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/WordJs_1.3_Openspec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Michael is not aware of this, but we recently shipped (its now GA) a table object that you can use in word. And gives you WAY more functionalities than just inserting the HTML.

Here is the documentation for the table object:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.table?view=office-js

btw your code has an error. the expected argument is a 2D array. so you need to supply something like this:

```js
   Word.run(function (context) {
            // Create a proxy object for the document body.
            var body = context.document.body;

            body.insertTable(2, 2, Word.InsertLocation.end, [["a","b"], ["c","d"]]);

            // Synchronize the document state by executing the queued commands, and return a promise to indicate task completion.
            return context.sync();
        }).catch(function (e) {

            console.log(e.message);
        })
```

hope this helps!!!

thanks!!
Juan (PM for the Word JavaScript API)

Comment: Hi Juan, I'm getting InvalidArgument when calling the method. Could you please explain requirement "a) Make sure you are using a build that supports the table API"? What if I'm using an installed version (not 365) of Office 2016? Should I install Office 2016 Deployment Tool anyway?

Comment: there was an issue with the Beta CDN version of Office.js, we are updating it right now, just please  wait a few days. The API was shipped as preview as part of the April 2016 update of Office just make sure you have a build later than 16.6965. Just go to File->Account and there will be an option to update Office.

Comment: The first link is broken, the documentation for the table object is now here : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/javascript/api/word/word.table?view=office-js

Comment: the link is fixed on my answer. Also note the API is now in GA.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [insertHTML method](http://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body#inserthtmlhtml-string-insertlocation-insertlocation) on any Range/Body/Paragraph object to accomplish this task. Here's the code:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
    context.document.body.insertHtml(
        "<table><tr><td>a</td><td>b</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td></tr></table>",
        Word.InsertLocation.end
    );
    return context.sync().then(function(){});
}).catch(function(error){});
```

-Michael Saunders (PM for Office add-ins)