# Insert Table in Word use Javascript API

Tags: ms-word, ms-office, office365, add-in, office-js

I am trying to use the Word add-in [JavaScript API](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/word/word-add-ins) to add a table with content like below Image
[image]

And this my code:

```
$('#addtbl').click(function () {
                Word.run(function (context) {
                    var tables = context.document.getSelection().tables;
                    tables.load();
                    return context.sync().then(function () {
                        tables.first.insertTable(2, 2, Word.InsertLocation.end);
                    }).then(context.sync);
                });
            });
```

It doesn't add table to my document. How can I add table with content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a few comments on your example:

1. you don't need to load the tables collection in order to insert a table in your document. You just need to insert it.
2. The parameters you are sending to the method are incorrect. Check out the sample below, you are missing the values from which you need to supply a 2-d array with the data you want to insert, this is the last parameter. Check our the reference [here](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.3_Openspec/reference/word/body.md#inserttablerowcount-number-columncount-number-insertlocation-insertlocation-values-string).

Here is an example.. i am adding a few types of tables you can insert, just change the arrays sent to the insertTable method.

```js
Word.run(function (ctx) {

            var fruits = [["Apple", "red", "round", "crunchy"], ["Banana", "yellow", "long", "mushy"], ["Pear", "green", "oblong", "variable"]];
            var fruitsNonuniform = [["Apple", "red"], ["Banana", "yellow", "long", "mushy"], ["Pear", "green", "oblong"]];
            var fruitsUnderfilled = [["Apple", "red", "", ""], ["Banana", "yellow", "long", "mushy"], ["Pear", "green", "oblong", ""]];

// parameters of the insert table: number of rows to insert, number of columns, insert location (in this case the table is inserted at the beginning of the document, and finally the values which is the array itself.
            var table = ctx.document.body.insertTable(fruits.length, fruits[0].length, "start", fruits);
            ctx.load(table);
            return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                table.style = "Grid Table 6 Colorful - Accent 2";
                return ctx.sync().then(function () {
                   
                });

            }).catch(function (e) {
                console.log(e.message);

            });
        });
```

Comment: also note that insertTable is a property of a range, so you can do body.insertTable or you could also do getSelection.insertTable, contentControl.insertTable etc etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this post here by Word PM Juan Balmori:

[Office Add-in development: Insert table in Word 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38139561/office-add-in-development-insert-table-in-word-2016)

Table objects are added to the Office-JS specifications as part of the 1.3 APIs. check the open spec:

http://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/WordJs_1.3_Openspec

Also make sure you are using a build that supports the table API.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Maarten's comment, a few other notes:

- You are missing a `.catch` statement, causing the error to get silently swallowed. You will have much better luck debugging this if you add a `.catch`
- For the `.first` API in particular, it may have been renamed to a method (`getFirst()`) IIRC.  But not sure which build and/or JS version combo will work here.
- While it's not an error per se, you don't need the `load` statement on the tables collection, since you're not actively reading back anything from the tables collection -- instead, you are retrieving a brand new table object.